# TYPO3: In an action controller, how to tell is an action is executed in backend or in frontend?

Tags: typo3, extbase

This is probably pretty simple, but I don't know where to look to find the answer. Suppose the same action is used in both frontend and backend, or suppose that I need a different behavior in `initializeAction` for frontend and for backend, how can I check whether the action is called from backend or from frontend?

Btw, I'm using `extbase`, and TYPO3 6.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it can be determined by `TYPO3_MODE` constant (preview for an example `ext_tables.php` generated by Builder)

This, for an example means that you trying to call the script from the 'outside':

```php
if (!defined('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}
```

Other quite common condition is:

```php
if (TYPO3_MODE == 'BE') {
    // this will execute only in the backend...
}
```

Anyway, I truly advice creating separate actions or even controllers for FE and BE, if you'll decide to use one action for both modes, you'll find it uncomfortable as soon as you'll write several extensions.

#### For TYPO3 ver. `11+`

The `TYPO3_MODE` const is deprecated as Sybille Peters mentions, therefore please check [the documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Deprecation-92947-DeprecateTYPO3_MODEAndTYPO3_REQUESTTYPEConstants.html) for other possibilities in newest versions. You can use i.e.:

```php
if (ApplicationType::fromRequest($request)->isFrontend()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using TYPO3_MODE to determine whether FE / BE is discouraged and deprecated, please see changelog https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Deprecation-92947-DeprecateTYPO3_MODEAndTYPO3_REQUESTTYPEConstants.html